# HTML video not playing on hover when page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Basically ,I have a page in which i have included some videos,
so that when i hover on any video ,it should play and when i mouseout from the video ,it should stop.
Everything is working fine when i visits the page first time or when i do hard refresh.
But when i reloads the same page again by refresh or when i hit the page url again in browser,
video does not play on hover. and also when i click mouse button somewhere else outside of video after doing page reload,then hover on video again works.

Here is the code which I am using:-

```
 <div  class="vid" >
<video width="100%" height="100%" class="thevideo" >
<source src="some path" >
</video>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 var figure = $(".vid").hover( hoverVideo, hideVideo);
   function hoverVideo(e) { $('.thevideo', this).get(0).play();  
    }
   function hideVideo(e) {
       $('.thevideo', this).get(0).pause();
       $('.thevideo', this).get(0).currentTime=0;
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your code in `$(document).ready()` like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var figure = $(".vid").hover( hoverVideo, hideVideo);
   function hoverVideo(e) { $('.thevideo', this).get(0).play();  
    }
   function hideVideo(e) {
       $('.thevideo', this).get(0).pause();
       $('.thevideo', this).get(0).currentTime=0;
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks CumminUp07 for your reply, I tried your solution,But still hover is not working when i hit url again after visiting the page